# Poisson process conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

> Penguins slide through a chute in a Poisson process at a rate of $2$ per minute. Each penguin has a $10$% chance of being an emperor penguin, independent of everything else. Given that $90$ penguins shot through the chute in an hour, what is the probability that $10$ were emperors?

I haven't come across a Poisson process question like this before, but figured that I should probably make use of the Binomial distribution, making use of the fact that given $X(t) = n$ for a Poisson process, then $X(s) \sim \text{Bin}(n,\frac{s}{t})$ when $s \leq t$.

So in this case, the probability that $10$ were emperors would follow a Binomial distribution with $n=90$ and $\frac{s}{t} = 0.1$. That would give an answer of
$${90 \choose{10}} (0.1)^{10} (0.9)^{80} = 0.125
$$

Now **a few problems**.

1. I got this question marked wrong on my assignment, so I must have the wrong answer! However I cannot figure out how my answer could be wrong, and in what other manner I could approach this question.
2. I don't really understand the notation used in the idea used in my own approach (from my notes). For $X(s) \sim \text{Bin}(n,\frac{s}{t})$, does $s$ represent the time period we are covering, which in this case is equivalent to $t$? If so, I don't really understand what $s/t$ is useful for in a Binomial distribution. In this case I sort of blindly followed a break in logic and used a Binomial with $0.10$ as my probability value because intuitively it made sense to me. I got part marks but no comments on my approach, so I'm unsure if they're purely out of sympathy or if I was on the right track?

Comment: Your answer looks, (_I daresay_), fine to me.

Comment: If the question is "What is the probability that the number of penguins in the first $24$ minutes was $30$ given that the number in the first hour is $90$?", then it would be correct to say that the number in the first $24$ minutes is distributed as $\mathrm{Bin}(90,24/60)$.  However, that is not what the question was.  So "$s/t$" is right for a different question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was actually just looking at my notes trying to understand that bit, that makes complete sense. I didn't want to ask as it seemed a bit irrelevant to my question, but thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the conditional distribution of the count of emperor penguins among the given total of $90$ penguins will be binomial with parameters $n=90, p=0.10$.   The fact that the penguins arrive in a Poisson process is irrelevant to the question.

$$\mathsf P(N_e=10\mid N_e+N_p=90) = \binom{90}{10} 0.10^{10}0.90^{80}$$

2. However, the notations for random variables $X(s), X(t)$ is more suggestive of count of penguins arriving in period lengths $s, t$.   This has nothing to do with the question.

I suspect that you have your notes confused.

Comment: Hm, that makes sense. No idea why I tried to use that idea from my notes, I imagine it confused some marker quite a bit! I just assumed my answer was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is ok except that the parts about $s$ and $t$ seems confused.  Only one time period is mentioned, and how much time it is doesn't matter because we are *given* the number of arrivals during that time. (If we were asked "What is the probability that the number of arrivals will be $90$?" that would be another matter.)  No ratio of times is involved.  The number $0.1$, the probability of each penguin's being an emperor penguin, does not come from a ratio of times.

Here's a guess: If the question is "What is the probability that the number of penguins in the first $24$ minutes was $30$ given that the number in the first hour is $90$?", then it would be correct to say that the number in the first $24$ minutes is distributed as $\mathrm{Bin}(90,24/60)$.  However, that is not what the question was.

Comment: The poisson process is a red herring. Once you know how many penguins came out, it doesn't matter how likely that was. All that matters is the probability that 10/90 penguins are emperor, since this is independent of everything else.